# Suppress AJAX Calls on a webpage using GreasyMonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

As part of my daily work, I need to fill data in a webpage containing a number of fields. The webpage is built such a way that on selection of each field, a AJAX request is sent for validation and fetching results. And there are approx 20 fields which take input. Further, I found that the code is written such a way that the data of all the 20 fields are sent in each of the AJAX request in order to fetch the results.

However, on slow connections, this causes inordinate delay that I have to wait for 5-10 seconds on selection of each field due to AJAX validation from server and page refresh. I want to write a Greasymonkey/Violentmonkey/Tapermonkey script to suppress the AJAX until I fill all the 20 fields.

Note: The onChange/click Events on the fields contain many other validations other than the AJAX call due to which I don't want to suppress the onChange/click events on the fields.

A typical selection is as under:

```
<h6 class="spin">Tube end<span class="facet-toggle"></span></h6>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li data-value="00any" class="  " data-display-value="Any Value" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Any Value </a> </li>

        <li data-value="bevelend" class="  " data-display-value="Bevel end" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Bevel end <i> 2</i> </a> </li>

        <li data-value="plainend" class="  " data-display-value="Plain end" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Plain end <i> 147</i> </a> </li>

        <li data-value="screwed" class="  " data-display-value="Screwed" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Screwed <i> 34</i> </a> </li>

        <li data-value="screwedandsocketed" class="  " data-display-value="Screwed and socketed" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Screwed and socketed <i> 9</i> </a> </li>

        <li data-value="screwedwithoneendsocket" class="  " data-display-value="Screwed with one end Socket" data-facet-name="C8948E"> <a> Screwed with one end Socket <i> 59</i> </a> </li>
    </ul>
<div class="facet-footer">&nbsp;</div>
```

[Developer Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTQ5Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the AJAX functions and filter out the URLs that are used for validation.

First, you need the read the code what function is used. There are two APIs.

[XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

You need to modify the code and filter out the URL you don't want.

If the page use Fetch you can use:

```
var ignoreURL = /validation/;

(function (fetch) {
    window.fetch = function(url, ...args) {
        if (!url.match(ignoreURL)) {
            return fetch(url, ...args);
        }
        return Promise.resolve({
           json: () => Promise.resolve({valid: true})
        });
    };
})(fetch);
```

If your page use `fetch` you need to investigate what requests are sent, if it's JSON and code use res.json() then you need to return whatever the script expects to get from the AJAX request. Here is just an example of `{valid: true}` but you need to check your exact requests.

If the code is using jQuery you need to look at what code the jQuery is using, if it uses XMLHttpRequest object to send AJAX requests you need to modify that object similar to fetch above, but it requires more work.